# MailChimp installation gives error when installing through composer in magento 2.3

Tags: git, magento, mailchimp, mailchimp-api-v3.0, magento-2.3

Hope all are good.

Recently we got an issue while installing mailchimp into magento 2.3 .
We installed it using composer by using command 
composer require mailchimp/mc-magento2 1.3.33

we are getting an error as

Failed to download mandrill/mandrill from dist: The "https://bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php/get/da3adc10042eafac2e53de141b358a52b8e53596.zip" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: System error
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: System error
    Now trying to download from source

After it tried from downloading to source the error is

[RuntimeException]
  Failed to execute git clone --no-checkout 'https://x-token-auth:***@bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php.git' && git fetch composer

Cloning into '/home/****/public_html/vendor/mandrill/mandrill'...
  fatal: unable to access 'https://x-token-auth:@bitbucket.org/mailchimp/mandrill-api-php.git/': Failed to connect to bitbucket.org port 443: Connection refused

Can anyone installed mailchimp in magento 2.3.if yes, please let me know how to resolve that error.

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot a repository. Now it downloads from your own repository. You should add the repo of mailchimp. So composer can get the right package.